# How publish ASP.NET Core to a server without stop iis (error : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Tags: asp.net-core, publish

When we publish our ASP.NET Core application and upload to the server, we get an error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

And when stop iis not error. How to upload without stopping IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you use web deploy to push to an IIS you own (a machine located in your datacenter) you can try to recycle the AppPool used by the web application you are trying to redeploy.

- Go to your IIS Management Console
- Right click the AppPool in question
- Choose the recycle option

Be aware that this would also 'restart' all other apps which are associated to this AppPool.

This 'should' work in most cases.

If you deploy to Azure you might consider using either a Linux App Service or some Docker deployment mechanism altogether. You cannot use the In-Process IIS ASP.NET Core modules in these cases as far as I am aware of but at least deployments don't randomly fail.